# Вопрос по теории вероятностей (от чайника)

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

Дано: имеется множество из 10 карт. 4 из этих карт находятся на руках противника. Среди этих 10 карт имеются 3 "опасные".
Задание: как посчитать вероятность того, что ХОТЯ БЫ ОДНА (любая) из "опасных" карт окажется среди этих 4 карт на руках у противника?

Comment: Мне бы формулу. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно и проще. Каково отрицание "хотя бы одна опасная карта"? Ни одной. Значит, вероятность выбрать хотя бы одну опасную карту = 1 - вероятность не выбрать ни одной опасной карты.

Всего способов выбрать 4 карты из 10:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Запись в скобках - американская...) А способов не выбрать ни одной опасной, только безопасные карты - это выбрать 4 из 7 безопасных карт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит, выбрать 4 карты так, чтобы среди них была хотя бы одна опасная = 210-35=175. А вероятность, соответственно, 175/210, как и у [CuriousBoy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093353/195342).

Просто считаем в одно действие :):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Кто не верит в эту вероятность - вот [исчерпывающий эксперимент](https://ideone.com/SXSPKa):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int total = 0, bad = 0;
    string s = "0123456789";
    do {
        if (s[0] < '3' || s[1] < '3' || s[2] < '3' || s[3] < '3') bad++;
        total++;
    } while(next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end()));
    cout << double(bad)/total << endl;
}
```

Comment: У меня тут "тяжёлый случай", и я не понимаю, как считается количество сочетаний. Может, кто-то подскажет, как эта функция называется, чтобы погуглить на эту тему? Я пытаюсь на питоне это всё написать...

Comment: Да очень просто. Например, есть 10 карт. Как выбрать 4 из них, сколькими способами? На первое место у нас 10 вариантов, на второе - остается 9, на третье... - всего 10*9*8*7 вариантов. Но это - *размещения*, где играет роль порядок карт. Если порядок не играет роли - то 4 карты мы их можем перетасовать 4! способами - вот и выходит 10*9*8*7/(1*2*3*4) = 10!/(6!*4!). Рассматривая N карт, из которых выбираем M - получим точно так же N!/((N-M)!M!). См., например, http://mathematichka.ru/school/combinatorics/combination.html или https://www.matburo.ru/tv_komb.php

Answer (score 1):

Посчитаем количество вариантов для выбора карт которые окажутся у противника - это количество сочетаний из 10 по 4 = 210.Из них условию задачи удовлетворяют те наборы из четверок в которых есть хотя бы одна опасная карта. Посчитаем сколько таких наборов. Наборов в которых встретились все три опасные карты будет 7 штук : зафиксировали 3 опасных и остаётся подобрать одну карту в набор,всего вариантов 7. Наборов в которых встретились две опасные карты - 63: тут фиксируются 2 опасные карты, а вариантов для остальных - количество сочетаний из 7 по 2, умножаем это количество на 3 поскольку вариантов для фиксации первых двух карт - 3, а наборов с одной опасной картой 105: фиксируем одну опасную карту,а подбираем остальные,вариантов для остальных - количество сочетаний из 7 по 3 = 35 и умножаем на 3 - количество вариантов для фиксации первой карты и того 105 . Тогда нам подходят 7+63+105=175 наборов.Тогда по классической вероятности - это кол-во вариантов которые удовлетворяют условию делить на общее кол-во вариантов. То есть 175/210=0.833 или 83%.

Comment: Что-то не то. Не сходится со здравым смыслом. Не может быть столь низкая вероятность. Но это на взгляд чайника. :)

Comment: Ошибка в логике. Если у соперника 4 карты, а опасных три, то наборов, в которые попали все три опасных - 7 штук: в каждом наборе 3 опасных карты, и одна из семи оставшихся, что дает 7 комбинаций. Аналогичная ошибка с 2 опасными и 1 опасной в наборе.